# How to use scanner to read accented characters from file in correct way?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have this method:

```
 public static void readFile(String input)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(input));){

            while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                String currentLine = sc.nextLine();
                if(sc.hasNextLine()){
                    String nextLine = sc.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("currentLine\t"+currentLine);
                    System.out.println("nextLine\t"+nextLine);
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

It works correctly, without any errors, or any problems, but this not write any content from the file. In the file I have some basic "lorem ipsum" text, just to see how this works. 
If in the file only latin characters are then this works correctly, but if is there any other characters (ex: áéűőúüöó) then this not write any content from the file. Where can I have the problem? How can I  resolve this?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Check how many lines are actually in the file. If there are no line breaks and everything is on one line, then the if condition will return false and nothing will print.

Comment: @LeoAso please check my updated question, this not works if there is characters such éáűőú...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have just single line and the bug is here:

```
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                String currentLine = sc.nextLine();
                if(sc.hasNextLine()){
```

you get the current line but print it only when there is next line.
In this way last line will be missing.

Please remove the IF condition.

EDIT:
After question editing please try to give proper encoding ex for UTF8:

```
new Scanner(new File(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
```

Comment: please check my updated question, this not works if there is characters such éáűőú...

Comment: Now it changes the question totally :)
Please try give proper encoding to scanner class like for example for UTF8:
`new Scanner(new File(input), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: what should I import to use this? I tried with `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets` but then throw this error: `no suitable constructor found for Scanner`

Comment: Scanner accepts string as charset name so please use:
`StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()`
updating answer...
but please use APPROPRIATE encoding name (this is just an example) - it depends which encoding is used by your input file.

Comment: that means you have probably some strange encoding. Please save your input file as UTF-8 and re-try, or change charset name to your encoding.